# Why hibernate created tabe not visible in the database

Tags: java, hibernate

If the console display this after running test class

```
07:32:36,883 DEBUG SchemaExport:377 - create table Employee1 (empId integer not null, name varchar(255), primary key (empId))
07:32:37,022  INFO SchemaExport:268 - schema export complete
07:32:37,024  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:170 - cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true
```

The table is not display in the database

```
package com.hibernate.chapter1; 

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration; 
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport; 

public class TestEmployee { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee1.class); 
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); 
    new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true); 
  } 
}
```

The test class looks as follows:

```
package com.hibernate.chapter1; 

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration; 
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport; 

public class TestEmployee { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee1.class); 
        config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); 
        new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How are you running Derby

Comment: By starting startNetworkServer.bat I have use the correct way for creating the database.

Comment: Ok so you're not running in-memory :) can you share your test class

Comment: package com.hibernate.chapter1;
                                                                     
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;                                               

public class TestEmployee {

 
 public static void main(String[] args) {                       
  AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
  config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee1.class);
  config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
  new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);

 }

}

Comment: Here do I need to set up the environment variables (path) for MySql?

Comment: I have created a new default schema,and it also not going to display the table inside that. can I please have an idea bout this issue..